# Strange behaviour of clojure trampoline

Tags: clojure

While trying to use `trampoline` to optimise tail recursion in my Clojure project, I came across some strange behaviour of the `trampoline` function.

```
=> (defn f [g] (fn [k & args] #(k (apply g args))))        
...
=> (trampoline (f list) println 1 2 3)        
(#<core$println clojure.core$println@54e517f6> 1 2 3)        
nil        
=> (((f list) println 1 2 3))        
(1 2 3)        
nil
```

I thought that `(trampoline (f list) ...)` and `((f list) ...)` gave the same result, but as you can see above, they don't. Would anyone explain what goes on here?

Comment: I don't really understand the purpose of using `println` here, but did you know `println` always returns `nil` (and things displayed are just side effects)?

Comment: I just used println for illustration. In my usage, the k argument is typically a consumer of the result of (apply g args). Using reverse instead of println would be a more meaningful example; in this case, I get (3 2 1 #<core$reverse clojure.core$reverse@5930dfaf>) for the first, and (3 2 1) for the second.

Answer (score 2):

Good catch!

You should report this bug to [Clojure Dev Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/clojure-dev) or to [Clojure Issue Tracker](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ).

Also note, that this bug can only be reproduced by calling `(apply list args)` inside of `trampoline` and only when `args` is bound to the tail of initial function's arguments list.

The actual problem here is that Clojure rebinds `args` to the whole list of initial function's arguments.

Here is a shorter example to reproduce your problem:

```clj
(defn foo [h & ts] (apply list ts))
(trampoline foo 1 2 3) ; => (1 2 3)
(foo 1 2 3) ; => (2 3)
```

Changing `(apply list ts)` to either `(list ts)` or `(apply vector ts)` will make this bug disappear.

Comment: If any clojure devs see this, I found the issue. The `doInvoke` method of `PersistentList/creator` ignores the index value of the `ArraySeq`. So the test in the for loop should be `i >= args.i` or equivalent, rather than `i >= 0`